# Three.JS CombinedCamera calling predefined parameters

Tags: parameters, three.js, camera, call, reset

I am using Combined Camera library for Three.JS scene and wants to set (reset) predefined parameters for each mode on switching.

```
function changeCameraMode(mode_){

    var s = "first person";
    if(mode_) { s = "birds view"; } 

    //false: first view, true: bird's eye
    console.log("mode: " + s);

    if(mode_) { camera.toOrthographic(); 

    camera.cameraO.position = cameraSettings.orpho.position;
    camera.cameraO.rotation.onChangeCallback._x = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.x;
    camera.cameraO.rotation.onChangeCallback._y = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.y;
    camera.cameraO.rotation.onChangeCallback._z = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.z;

    camera.cameraO.top = cameraSettings.orpho.top;
    camera.cameraO.left = cameraSettings.orpho.left;
    camera.cameraO.bottom = cameraSettings.orpho.bottom;
    camera.cameraO.right = cameraSettings.orpho.right;

    camera.quaternion._x = 0.17446644315139806; 
    camera.quaternion._y = 0.40250876457862955;
    camera.quaternion._z = 0.07844478023909554;
    camera.quaternion._w = 0.8952064404955571;

    camera.rotation.x = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.x;
    camera.rotation.y = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.y;
    camera.rotation.z = cameraSettings.orpho.rotation.z;

    camera.position = cameraSettings.orpho.position;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    } 

    else { camera.toPerspective(); }

}
```

I have played with almost all variables (see above) but nothing really happens.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have used it with FirstPersonControl.js and actually what I have to do is this:

```
controls.lat = value0_;  
controls.lon =  value1_; 
controls.phi =  value2_;
controls.theta =  value3_;

camera.lookAt(controls.target);
```